# dns brocken, what's archive.ubuntu.com IP

Tags: apt, dns, repository, dnsmasq

I've installed xenial in a container and for some reason dnsmasq got left out. Now I can't update or install packages. I tried to edit /etc/apt/sources.list and edit the repo addresses to include the IP addresses. However I couldn't find out the IP address of archive.ubuntu.com. I tried with ping, traceroute, dig, even wget and all report different addresses and none of those work (not even through the browser). Can anybody tell me what the correct IP address is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already tried this IP for Ubuntu?

[image: IP address for Ubuntu]

Comment: Yes that's it! Tanks you very much!